# Add php variable to MySQL using AJAX but hide value in DOM

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm building a simple To Do app and connects with Facebook.

I want people to be able to create a new To Do list and register it to database (I use Ajax for that). I will place the code below and my question after that.

```
<a id="submit-list" href="#">
    <div class="list-adder">
        <input class="hidden" name="unique_url" id="uniqueUrl"   type="text" value="<?php echo generateRandomString(); ?>" />
        <input class="hidden" name="user_id" id="userId" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>" />
        <input class="hidden" name="user_name" id="userName" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['FULLNAME']; ?>" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="List Title" name="add_list" class="add_list" id="addList" />
        <span id="submit_list">Add List</span> <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

So here I take the list unique URL, Title and the facebook User id and Full name

I send over the details to Ajax and from there to the database. Everything works perfectly. However, there might be a security issue. If I inspect this form I get the user id and name in the source code as seen in this screenshot: 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/59dab8aca0694f89989ef1e0f59b9fc4.png
[image: two muppets]
And if I edit the user id or name the edited data is sent to the database.

Is there any way I can make sure the real data of the user is sent to the database instead of the edited data?

Thank you.

Comment: if it's ajax, then you can intercept the actual form submission with JS code, add/remove/modify whatever form values you want, and then do ANOTHER submission with the actual data.

Comment: Just add some validation before you insert to the database? You already know user_id should be the same as $_SESSION['FBID']. If its not tell the user the data is invalid.

Comment: @MarcB If the validation is client side then its still vulnerable

Comment: @user1: true, but that's true of anything client-side. you can't prevent a user from fiddling with stuff in their browser. you can only make it harder for them.

Comment: Radu033, what is the point of having the user_id and user_name fields anyway? Can't you just submit the form without it and in PHP insert using the $_SESSION values

Comment: @user1 OMG thank you, I was working for more than 12 hours without a good break and I couldn't think of anything at the time of opening this ticket. Thank you, you for opening my eyes on such a simple issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to put something into a form is because you need that data in the subsequent request *that you can't get from somewhere else.*

But you already have this data in the user's session - there's no point in printing it into the form in order to make it available to the next request - *it's already available to the next request.*

Remove the `user_id` and `user_name` fields from your form, and when constructing your query instead of reading those values from the request, read them from the session

Answer (score 0):

This perfect solution is to use SESSION, but if you want to use it as input you can delete the fields after the page is initiated.

Not bullet proof though.

```
var USER_ID   = null;
var USER_NAME = null;

$(function()
{
   USER_ID   = $('#userId').val();
   USER_NAME = $('#userName').val();

   $('#userId').remove();
   $('#userName').remove();

   $.post('..', {'userId' : USER_ID }) ..
});
```